# Consume web service without adding service reference in C# 4.0

Tags: web-services, dynamic, c#-4.0

Is there any existing way to consume web services (SOAP, JSON, etc.) leveraging `dynamic` keyword from C# 4.0?

I'm looking for as lightweight implementation as possible (without calling wsdl.exe or such).

Comment: have you looked at WCF REST ?

Comment: its uses REST.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529

Answer (score 0):

You can just share the contract (the interface) between the client and server. Then the ChannelFactory class will allow you to create communication channels to the server based on either pure code or a configuration file (app or web.config).